# How to align modal popup panel extreme right for AJAX Modal Popup Extender?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Ajax modalpopupextender control in child page in master-child relationship. I want to align modalpopup extreme right

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="btnShow"
        CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none; right: 0px !important;">
        This is an ASP.Net AJAX ModalPopupExtender Example<br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var id = null;
        function movePanel() {
            var pnl = $get("ContentPlaceHolder1_Panel1");
            if (pnl != null) {
                pnl.style.right = "0px !important";
                pnl.style.top = "0px";
                pnl.style.left = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I have tried various solution some of them are in code part. As per my homework, i tried using X and Y ModalPopupExtender. But  X and Y for doesn't allow calc like  x=100vw-width of panel;

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it.I have considered length of panel=550px.

```
<input type="hidden" name="checkyear" id="checkyear" runat="server" value="" />
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_checkyear").value = screen.width-550;
        });
</script>
```

//In Code behind

```
mp1.X = Convert.ToInt32(checkyear.Value);
```